# How to create jqplot chart on server side as image without rendering on browser?

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, jqplot

I have created jqplot charts on client side web pages. Now I want to create a thread that creates those charts and send them in PDF to specific emails. Is there any way to create those charts in back end thread without rendering on browser?

Comment: I am going to guess no since JQPlot is a jquery based JavaScript charting engine.  It would need at the very least a running JavaScript engine like Rhino or Nashhorn and then all the correct libraries like Jquery loaded to try and render your chart.  If you need to render server side charts in Java I suggest something like http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

Comment: jfreecharts are good but they do not render the graph nicely as jqplot does

Comment: Agreed but at least they are server side charts without JS.

Comment: ok any other library for server side ?